# Check dump result

Tags: batch-file, mysql

I've got a script which launch this MySQL command :

```
mysqldump -u login -ppass --routines --triggers --databases db >> dump.sql
```

It's working fine, but I want to check the result of the dump in case of an error.

For example, if the base is stopped or down, an error is displayed. How can I store the error code in a variable to check it (e.g. with an `if` statement) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found out !

```
mysqldump -u login -ppass --routines --triggers --databases db >> dump.sql
if errorlevel 1 (echo Dump failed) else (echo Dump success)
```